# IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.util.UUID] not specified in Unit Tests After Upgrading Spring Boot from 3.1.x to 3.2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I recently attempted to bump the Spring Boot version from 3.1.3 to 3.2.3 in my project, and now all of my simple unit tests that use UUID as parameter are failing due to this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument of type [java.util.UUID] not specified, and parameter name information not available via reflection. Ensure that the compiler uses the '-parameters' flag.`

Here an example of such test:

```
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "Entity id: {0}")
    @MethodSource("retrieveIds")
    void shouldRetrieveSingleIfExist(UUID id) {
        client.get()
                .uri("/entities/{id}", id)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.id").isEqualTo(id.toString());
    }
```

I haven't found any relevant information online (this issue looks similar [Error "Name for argument of type [java.util.UUID] not specified, and parameter name information not found in class file either"with spring 3.2 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77635974/error-name-for-argument-of-type-java-util-uuid-not-specified-and-parameter-n) but the proposed solutions did not help). Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be? When I revert to version 3.1.3, all tests pass successfully.

UPDATE:

I tried this configuration without any effect:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArguments>-parameters</compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```